# Starting a service that start an activity on device boot

Tags: android, startup, boot

im trying to start an application on device boot.

my code is as follow

1- firstly the main class which contain a background thread (asynctask) that send data to a mysql database.

2- Service class

```
package com.seven.ex.helper;

import com.seven.ex.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class service extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
{
    Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.class);
    intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intents);
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}
}
```

3- BootUpReceiver class

```
package com.seven.ex.helper;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,service.class);
    arg0.startService(intent);
    Log.i("Autostart", "started");
}

}
```

4- the android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gpstracking"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />




   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.seven.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service android:name=".service" 
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
    </service>

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>        

    </application>


   </manifest>
```

The main method is working correctly before i tried to start it on boot.
Also the app still working after i ignore the android error on boot (The App Closed)

in the log cat am getting a class not found  exception

can you please help ?

Comment: Does the code fail to locate the Service or the AndroidGPSTrackingActivity class?

Comment: when i boot up the emulator a force closed error appear. then if i open the application by clicking on the icon it work smoothly. the logcat show nothing until i opened the app by clicking on the icon

Comment: I understand, but you write "in the log cat am getting a class not found exception" and I would like to know what class it fails to find.

Comment: logcat: 09-24 12:15:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.ex.BootUpReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ex.BootUpReceiver
 ..... it can't find the BootUpReceiver class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest you have assigned package: com.example.gpstracking. When u then define .BootUpReceiver. The system should expect to locate the class at com.example.gpstracking.BootUpReceiver.

Please try and change the package .BootUpReceiver to the full path com.seven.ex.helper.BootUpReceiver. The same goes for AndroidGPSTrackingActivity as this should be com.seven.ex.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity as far as I can tell.

Comment: copy&paste is a b****

Comment: @bofredo idd can be :) especially in xml and the like - no compiler or lint to save you. Not in cases like this anyway...

Comment: it works ... thank you .. i downloaded a plain source code which read gps data and start working on it , then i refactor(rename) the package name and i thought eclipse will change the name everywhere even in the manifest file but it didn't. Thank You Very Much ; i'll accept your answer @cYrixmorten

Comment: You are welcome. Things like that happen to all of us and is not easy to spot.

Comment: The answer above remove the force closed error but when i boot up the emulator the application won't start automatically?

Comment: I do not know what the exact purpos of your activity is. But if it has an UI and you want it to be started with the device, one possible option is to add: <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> together with the MAIN and LAUNCHER part. This gives the user an option to start your app, or to start the default home screen. If it is just background processing, that logic might aswell be in the service running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Your Service won't work like it is at the moment. You will have to move the stuff from onStart() to onStartCommand() and then return whether the service is sticky or not. The problem is that the onStart()-method has a good chance of not getting called at all (as it is deprectaed by now).

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

        //do your stuff here

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```